# Android-Layout: RelativeLayout automatic re-sizing edittext fields possible?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to understand how relative layout works.
I know if I use LinearLayout, I will have two edit text fields, side by side, horizontally.
Using 'weight' will make edittext fields re-sized based on the screen size  only.  (It will look odd probably, but it will do it).

I know that linearlayout is not the most efficient.  Can I use relative layout and have the same effect?  I don't want to specify a size, I just want to expand edittexts.

What would the xml looks like with a such linearlayout?

Thank you,
 Mike

Comment: What confuses me is `Can use relative layout and have the same affect?` does this mean you want a RelativeLayout code too?

Answer (score 1):

One of the things I can see most android developers spend their lives on is layouts.

It seems you can do what I want with RelativeLayouts, but only for multiples of 2..at least what I have found so far.  With the button center, two buttons are put on the same line, each taking about half the screen.  Without button center they overlap each other.  Wonder if it is worth it.

Hope this helps and thanks everybody!

```
<View android:id="@+id/button_center" android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button android:id="@+id/btnButton1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button 1" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_center"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/btnButton2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button 2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this could be done with alignLeft/alignRight, but sadly it seems a nested LinearLayout is required.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Left" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Right" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you just used width="fill_parent" and height="fill_parent" in the EditText fields (and maybe use some padding or margins)?

Comment: Thought I gave that a try and just had both stacked on top of each other..Perhaps I confused something.

Answer (score 0):

Rememeber that weights are not percentages. Weights will weight things according to their original size. In order to accomplish what you want with weights just add a android:weightSum to your LinearLayout.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Left" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Right" />
</LinearLayout>
```